# Wireless driver fails to activate on an hp pavilion dv4 w/vista home premium

Tags: 11.10, wireless, hp

can I download a different wireless driver and put it on a thumb drive to install on my hp or run windows on the hp and connect to the Internet and install to it and then reboot to Ubuntu? I'm using my Toshiba w/Ubuntu to trouble shoot?  thank you.

Prob, solved,, using Pinguy 12.04,, running great off cd,,,

Answer (score 1):

You may need a program called ndiswrapper to get your wireless working. This is how I got mine working. I installed ndiswrapper, then used it to install the `.inf` driver file from a CD. Then I installed gnome network admin and used it to connect.

The terminal command to start the ndiswrapper install should be:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```

And for network admin:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-network-admin
```

In the network settings, enter the SSID for your network, then restart the computer and it will auto connect. These instructions require a hardline (such as Ethernet) network connection to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had to do to get my wireless working. I also have a HP dv4-1225dx. I installed from a CD, which I'd burned the .iso to, and then I went into the "try ubuntu" option. (This was all discovered through trial and error.) I downloaded the proprietary drivers for the wireless, then went into the option System > Administration > Network Tools then clicked on the Netstat tab, and then chose the option for "Active Network Services." (My home wireless network showed up.) Then, once the the wireless network was up and running, I chose to install from within the desktop, and it finally retained the wireless after installing. I hope that helps because I'm just a newbie! :)

Comment: Thanks sillylyllie,I'll give that a try, I'm going to format the whole thing and start over and install from a CD I'll make from my main Toshiba PC.,,,I will update if I can get it to work.